# Netbeans 6.5 generates a lib folder when creating a GUI

Tags: netbeans, jar, netbeans6.5

How do I create a jar that incorporates the lib folder so I can email a single jar.  As it is if I don't include the lib folder and the jar folder the jar will not work.

I would like to add the lib folder to the main jar so I only need to send someone a single jar.

Comment: that's what i've done so far but i was just trying to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this article](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/apache-ant-how-to-include-multiple-jar-files-in-a-single-jar-file/) on using the Ant [jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) to include other files in a jar:

> Ant Jar task actually allows you to include multiple **zipfileset** as sub-elements. You can use zipfileset to include contents of other jar (and zip files) within your (big) jar file.

If that doesn't work, you also might be able to use the [zip task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) to zip up the folder and jar.